# Rails Event Pages for Every Day of the Year

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, ruby-on-rails-4, all-in-one-event-calendar

I'm creating an event application in Rails 4 and am wondering how I would approach a solution to the following problem. I have events and I want to display them on a date page.

For example if I have two events on August 24th I would like to show both of those events on a the August 24 page (/events/08/24/2015). I'm not sure how to generate pages for the current and next year in rails and how to properly setup the routing.

Can someone help me with a solution and/or a good place to start? Not quite sure how to approach this problem. Want to do something similar to this: http://omahype.com/2015/08/24

Comment: i hope these links will give you the start
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421281/rails-routes-with-dates
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317783/rails-routes-with-date
http://asciicasts.com/episodes/203-routing-in-rails-3

Comment: @athar thanks I'll check them out.